# I need to vary the duty cycle between 50% and 70% of a PWM signal

Tags: pwm, duty-cycle

So I used a comparator to compare a sawtooth signal and a reference voltage and I obtained the PWM signal at the output of the comparator. My question is what formula can I use to vary the duty cycle of the PWM signal as I like? 
This is the part of the circuit which adjust the duty cycle of my PWM signal.

[image]

I was thinking to use a potentiometer between 2 resistors and to vary the duty cycle by varying the values of the resistances. 
+/- Vps=+/-15V

Thanks in advance!

---

Comment: You ask for a formula but then you say you're thinking to use a potentiometer? At any rate, if this is a dynamic case, then simply remove the pot and use the other input as the reference. See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/300870/95619), for example.

Comment: Is mandatory to use a potentiometer, so that when i set it on '0' the duty cycle is 50% and when i set it on '1' the duty cycle is 70%.

Comment: What is the range of your sawtooth?

Comment: Vmin=-11.75V and Vmax= 11.25V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Work out what your sawtooth minimum voltage is. Let's call that *V<sub>min</sub>*.
- Work out what your sawtooth maximum voltage is. Let's call that *V<sub>max</sub>*.
- Now work out the voltage for 50% (half-way) between *V<sub>min</sub>* and *V<sub>max</sub>*. Let's call that *V<sub>50</sub>*.
- Then work out the voltage for 70% between *V<sub>min</sub>* and *V<sub>max</sub>*. Let's call that *V<sub>70</sub>*.

You've chosen a 1 kΩ pot so now work out the current through that from \$ I = \frac {V_{max} - V_{min} }{1k} \$.

Can you work out what value you require for R5 and R6 now so that the ends of the pot are held at the required voltages?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109253/discussion-on-answer-by-transistor-i-need-to-vary-the-duty-cycle-between-50-and).