# Vary duty cycle in PULSE in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, pulse

In a simulation using LTSpice, I would like to sweep the on-time (duty cycle) of a pulsed voltage produced using the "PULSE" waveform.

I am able to run separate simulations using ".step" to vary to on-time, but I could not find a way to vary T-on as a function of time or of another voltage.

I understand I could build a PWM source using a comparator etc, but PULSE is convenient and I am able to set rise and fall times etc. So if there is a way to achieve this using a voltage source and the "PULSE" function, that would be excellent.

Comment: Can you set rise and fall times dynamically though?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to sweep duty cycle over time in LTspice](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/300870/is-there-a-way-to-sweep-duty-cycle-over-time-in-ltspice)

Comment: This indeed solves the problem. However, now I wonder how I can have a non-ground reference for this signal.

Comment: PULSE() needs to be fully defined before running the simulation (or each separate simulation in the case of using `.step`).  This is because the SPICE engine explicitly puts in "breakpoints" (at each rise/fall corner) into the timestep control algorithm to force it to calculate solutions at those points.  This helps avoid convergence failure.  PWL() does the same thing, but it takes it longer to unroll all the points at the beginning of a simulation, especially if you're doing a `repeat forever`.